# How do I get Highcharts to update axis label positions when I have updated their text asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to find a way to smoothly update individual axis labels on a Highcharts chart, after the initial render.

Effectively, I want to create an asynchronous `formatter` function for the axis labels, a bit like what is mentioned in this GitHub thread:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6824

The suggestion in that thread is to use the `.attr` function to update the text value of the underlying SVG element.

This works great and can be seen in the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkwx5a4d/

My problem now is getting Highcharts to reflow the axis to update its label positions. Otherwise, Highcharts doesn't perceive the label to have changed size and the label ends up cropped.

I have tried various combinations of `reflow()`, `redraw()` and lower-level `getBbox()` methods with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use chart.events, `load()` which is fire after the initial of chart and `redraw()` every time you want to reload the axis.

```
events: {
  redraw: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      labelToUpdate.tick.label.attr({
        text: 'Redraw() here is a long label'
      });
    }, 1000);
  },
  load: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      labelToUpdate.tick.label.attr({
        text: 'Load() here is a long label'
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wyxcL3b/

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to figure out how to ensure the new axis label's position is updated correctly for its new size, so it is not cropped.